# Jquery $.ajax() always returns xhr.status as request aborted on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a JSON Service deployed on local pc, I'm working on ASP.net/C# and the data returned in IE 9 is a valid JSON response, checked with formatters and parsers.

Below is the JQuery Call (using JQuery version 1.7.1), I am making in a HTML file.

`http://mylocalhostpc:2483/Portfolio.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mylocalhostpc/JSONService/ServiceHandler.ashx?seed=ptr&cnt=2",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.results[0]) {
                var htmlText = data.results[0];
                var jsonObject = parseAndConvertToJsonObj(htmlText);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("footer-bottom").innerHTML = "Could not load the page.";
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status,thrownError) {
            switch (xhr.status) {
                case 200:
                    alert(xhr.status + ":- " + thrownError);
                    break;
                case 404:
                    alert('File not found');
                    break;
                case 500:
                    alert('Server error');
                    break;
                case 0:
                    alert('Request aborted: ' + !xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('Unknown error ' + xhr.status + ":- " + thrownError);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I receive the error message saying 'Request aborted: true'  every time.
However when I check the URL:

`http://mylocalhostpc/JSONService/Default.aspx?seed=ptr&cnt=2`

The following data is retuned sucessfully.

```
{ "Table" : [ { 
    "Product_Active" : true,
    "Product_DateAdded" : "/Date(1349352480000+0530)/",
    "Product_ISBN" : "9788179637494",
    "Product_Id" : 71,
    "Product_Price" : 45,
    "Product_Rating" : 5
  },
  { 
    "Product_Active" : true,
    "Product_DateAdded" : "/Date(1349352480000+0530)/",
    "Product_ISBN" : "9789350492536",
    "Product_Id" : 142,
    "Product_Price" : 150,
    "Product_Rating" : 5
  }
] }
```

web.config file code

```
<urlMappings>
  <add url="~/Default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/ServiceHandler.ashx"/>
```

Code behind for service handler - ServiceHandler.ashx.cs

```
public class ServiceHandler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.QueryString["seed"] != null)
    {
        string searchstring = string.Empty;
        Products oProducts = new Products();
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";

        switch (context.Request.QueryString["seed"].ToString())
        {
            case "pra":
            // prODUCT aLL
                context.Response.Write(ProcessingRequest.Serialize(oProducts.getAllProducts("0", "")));
                break;
            case "ptr":
                // pRODUCTS tOP rATED
                searchstring = context.Request.QueryString["cnt"] == null ? "20" : context.Request.QueryString["cnt"].ToString();
                context.Response.Write(ProcessingRequest.Serialize(oProducts.getTopRatedProducts(searchstring)));
                break;
            default:
                context.Response.Write("Invalid service request, please check the url.");
                break;
        }
        context.Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Write("Invalid service request, please provide valid seed.");
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am making any mistake, please help me resolve this?

I tried using dataType as 'jasonp' and 'script' as well but no luck the error changes to 'Unknown error undefined'

PS: After more effort I got the following error:

Added a code as under in my jquery error handler

`case 200:
    alert(xhr.status + ":- " + thrownError);
    break;`

which returned me the error code as

> 200:- Error: jQuery171049959372938610613_1356351917595 was not called

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why are you using `ServiceHandler.ashx` instead of `Default.aspx` in the ajax call? Do you get the same behavior if you swap them?

Comment: Is your _calling_ script running on the same domain and port (mylocalhostpc:2483)?

Comment: Hi mgibsonbr, I understand your concern, the behavior is same in both the cases i.e. with ServiceHandler.ashx as well as with Default.aspx. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Salman A, Yes and No,  the calling script is on same domain but not on the same port. I tried hosting it on localhost with port 8080 but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you you have to use it this way:

```
success: function (data) {
   $.each(data.Table, function(i, resp){
        if (resp) {
            var htmlText = resp;
            var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(htmlText);
            console.log(jsonObject);
        } else {
            $("#footer-bottom").html("Could not load the page.");
        }
   });
},
```

you can try with this too:

```
success: function (data) {
   $.each(data.Table, function(i, resp){

            console.log(resp);

   });
},
```

Comment: Hi Jai, Thanks for your reply, however if I check the console the request is getting aborted much earlier. Can you please suggest how I can invoke the request it correctly from JQuery? The problem is it does not run into sucess: block.

Comment: just updated the answer. Plz can you test it and confirm the status of console.

Comment: I added your code with data.Table, however no luck I also tried modifying some other stuff but getting the '200:- Error: jQuery171049959372938610613_1356351917595 was not called' as updated now...Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved by hosting both the service and the client on different servers.